Cannot Get/ Error in browser when i run react project
When I run a react project from Github I get an "Cannot Get/" error.The things I did were: "npm run dev" for the frontend and "npm start" for the backend.I ran the "npm i" code for both and installed the necessary packages.
I got this result in the browser.
Github project: https://github.com/eminbasbayan/full-stack-e-commerce
enter image description here
The things I did were: "npm run dev" for the frontend and "npm start" for the backend.I ran the "npm i" code for both and installed the necessary packages.
